# Reuse code in AutoMapper ForMember mappings

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm working on a solution with `Entity Framework Core` and `AutoMapper` (version 9).
The mapping from my entity classes to DTOs is done with projections.

```cs
var dto = await context.Companies
    .ProjectTo<MyDto>(config, new { departmentName = "Sales" });
```

In the mapping, I select a certain department.

```cs
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        string departmentName = null;

        CreateMap<Company, MyDto>()
            .ForMember(m => m.DepartmentLocation, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                src.Divisions.SelectMany(dv => 
                    dv.Departments.Where(d => d.Name == departmentName)
                )
                .Single().Location));
    }
}
```

---

Is it possible to move the code to select the department to another (private) method within the profile class?

---

This code will also be needed in the mapping of other members of the DTO.

I tried to move the code to another method, but then the Department's collection of a company is not populated. Probably because EF can't translate the method to SQL. I also tried to rewrite the method to an expression of Func that returns a department, but then I can't use the result directly to access the department properties in the mapping.

```cs
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
  public MyProfile()
    {
        string departmentName = null;

        CreateMap<Company, MyDto>()
            .ForMember(m => m.DepartmentLocation, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                SelectDepartment(src, departmentName).Location)
            );
    }

    private Department SelectDepartment(Company company, string departmentName)
    {
        var department = company.Divisions
            .SelectMany(Departments.Where(d => d.Name == departmentName)
            .First();

        if (department == null)
            throw new AutoMapperMappingException($"Department '{departmentName}' not found!");

        return department;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try caching the department in a source property instead. But do check the SQL before and after to understand the impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a half of a solution for you, but I will post it anyway. You can get the mapping done by creating a method that provides an expression. The problem is - how to throw an exception if the fitting department wasn't found, since you cannot throw one in an expression. What I would suggest is to throw the exception after the mapping since you have to query for the data anyway.

```cs
public class MyMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MyMappingProfile()
    {
        string departmentName = "Foo";

        CreateMap<Company, MyDto>()
            .ForMember(m => m.DepartmentLocation, opt => opt.MapFrom(SelectDepartment(departmentName)));
    }

    private Expression<Func<Company, string>> SelectDepartment(string departmentName)
        => (company) => company.Divisions
            .SelectMany(division => division.Departments)
            .Where(department => department.Name == departmentName)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .Location;
}
```

EF Core will generate nice query:

```sql
SELECT(
    SELECT TOP(1) [d0].[Name]
    FROM [Division] AS[d]
          INNER JOIN [Department] AS [d0] ON [d].[Id] = [d0].[DivisionId]
    WHERE ([c].[Id] = [d].[CompanyId]) 
        AND ([d0].[Name] = @__departmentName_0)) 
    AS [DepartmentLocation]
FROM [Company] AS[c]
```

Usage:

```cs
var result = dbContext
    .Set<Company>()
    .ProjectTo<MyDto>(mapperConfiguration)
    .ToList();

result.ForEach(myDto =>
{
    if (myDto.DepartmentLocation == null)
    {
        throw new AutoMapperMappingException("Department was not found!");
    }
});
```

Comment: In the mean time I rearranged my code a little bit. In my EF query I run all the expressions I need, on the lowest object in the object tree I call ProjectTo. Data I need from higher objects in the tree are resolved by navigation properties. That way my mappings become much simpler and I don't have to run expressions inside the mapper.
But your answer is still valid as a part of the solution, one should use expressions like you've shown to build up the correct SQL.

Comment: This seems to work fine for sharing the expression in multiple DTO's. I have the issue that I don't only want to map the Location but also for example the CostCenter of the same Company. I can easily do this bu then the generated SQL contains the QueryExpression 2x. It would be nice to have a general join and use the values from there. Any idea how to tackle this?